# Adding columns to the default when viewing form submissions

Tags: cognito-forms

If I want to view my list of forms submitted, how can I change the default so that the company name and patient name always show up in the columns?

This way I can view who the form is for without having to click on it to open it.

Answer (score 0):

I'm a developer with [Cognito Forms](https://www.cognitoforms.com).

You can set the shown Columns on the Entries page. This would let you see the different information that you would like without having to click on each entry. At the moment we do not have a way to save the Columns that have been set up. We do have a feature in the works, [Save Entry View](https://trello.com/c/T0qvZ1uq), that would let you save this set up so that You do not have to update the Columns each time you load the Entries page.